# How to add block comments in HTML?

Tags: html

I know there is a way to comment out blocks of code, but I can't find any help using Google. All searches lead to other HTML related things but not what I'm looking for.

For example I want to have code in my site I don't want to have function yet so I want to comment it out respectively.